# Proof of the following statement

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing, normed-spaces

My proof of the above statement in the forward direction is as follows:

For linear operators we have $T_a$ is surjective iff $\text{Im}T_a=\ell^\infty$. Suppose $T_a$ is sujective which implies that $\text{Im}T_a=\ell^\infty$ and assume $\inf_{n\geq 1}|a_n|=0$ which implies $\exists a_i=0$ for some $i\geq 1$.

Now let $x=(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with $x_i\neq 0$, then $T_ax=(a_n)_{n\geq 1}(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\in\ell^\infty$. But $\nexists x'\in\ell^\infty\,s.t\,T_ax'=x$ and hence $\text{Im}T_a\neq\ell^\infty$ which implies $T_a$ is not sujective which is a contradiction. So $\inf_{n\geq 1}|a_n|>0$.

Is this correct?

I also had an alternative proof:

For linear operators we have $T_a$ is surjective iff $\text{Im}T_a=\ell^\infty$. Suppose $T_a$ is sujective which implies that $\text{Im}T_a=\ell^\infty$ and assume $\inf_{n\geq 1}|a_n|=0$ which implies $\exists a_i=0$ for some $i\geq 1$.

So $T_ax'=(x_n)_{n\geq 1}\in\ell^\infty$ which implies $x'=\left(\frac{x_n}{a_n}\right)_{1\geq n}\in\ell^\infty$. But if $x'=(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ with $x_i\neq 0$ we have $\frac{x_i}{a_i}=\frac{x_i}{0}$ which is undefined and hence we must have $\inf_{n\geq 1}|a_n|>0$ in order for $T_a$ to be surjective.

If both are correct which is better out of the two?

Comment: Neither proof is correct. $\inf_{n\geq 1} \{|a_n|\} = 0$ does not mean there exists $i$ such that $a_i = 0$. Just take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @DionelJaime Thanks, not sure why I treated the infimum like the minimum, though I am unsure how taking $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ would help. I would appreciate if you could explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $T_a$ is surjective. If $\inf |a_n| =0$, then we may assume that  $a_{n}\to 0$ (otherwise we pass to a subsequence). Since $T_a$ is surjective and $(1-\tfrac 1n)_n \in \ell^\infty$, there exists $(u_n)_n \in \ell^\infty$ such that $a_n u_n =1 - \tfrac 1n~(n \ge 1)$. But, LHS converges to zero and RHS converges to one.

Conversely, suppose that $\inf|a_n|  >0$. Then, given any $(y_n)_n \in \ell^\infty$ the sequence $x_n= \frac{y_n}{a_n}$ is in $\ell^\infty$ and $y_n = a_n x_n$.

Comment: Yeap. In the first part you can take any sequence that does not converge to zero